Get deployment rollout status with java k8 client
Is there a way to use the Java Kubernetes Client to get the status of a rollout (in progress or completed)?
I would like the equivalent of this:
kubectl rollout status deployments/my-service
The kubectl command will display if a rollout is in progress or finished
